# How to make FileSystemWatcher trigger action after files are created and closed?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, filesystemwatcher

I'm using the following code to start

```
$folder = '....' 
$filter = '*.csv' 
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite' }
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    ... #execute a program to read the files, 
    ... #may fail because file is still being writing..... }
```

However, I the action is triggered as soon as the file is created. There may be hundreds of hug files to be dumped/copied in the folder. Is it possible to test if the files writing finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```
Try {
  [IO.File]::OpenWrite($File).Close()
  #Do something with file
}
Catch {}
```

If the file is done being written to and has been closed the `[IO.File]::OpenWrite($File).Close()`
will open the file for write, then immediately close it.  If it's still being written to it won't be able to get a write lock, the command will fail and the script will drop through to the Catch block and wait for the next LastWrite event.